# Почему написанный как обычная функция компонент возвращается пустой

Tags: reactjs

[image: Подключенный в Layout компонент multipleHoles, приходит в DOM пустым]

multipleHoles проверял console.log'ом в Layout'e, он точно подключён.
Пример взял из офф туториала
facebook react composition-vs-inheritance
Рабочий пример тут:
skunshd.github.io/react-test-example/
Source code тут:
https://github.com/SkunSHD/react-quick-start-examples

```
export function SplitPane(props) {
  return (
    <div className="SplitPane">
      <div className="SplitPane-left">
        {props.left}
      </div>
      <div className="SplitPane-right">
        {props.right}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Contacts() {
  return <div className="Contacts" />;
}

export function Chat() {
  return <div className="Chat" />;
}


import { SplitPane, Contacts, Chat } from './multipleHoles/SplitPane'

export default function multipleHoles() {
  return (
    <SplitPane
      left={
        <Contacts />
      }
      right={
        <Chat />
      } />
  );
}

import multipleHoles from './multipleHoles'

export default class Layout extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
       <div>

        <WelcomeDialog />
        <multipleHoles />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

import Layout from './components/Layout'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Layout />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

(Импорты компонентов убрал нарочно)

Comment: Ну и да, вас минуснули явно за скриншоты кода вместо кода, здесь так не принято и где-то в правилах написано так не делать

Comment: В общем с ходу ошибок в коде не вижу, не могли бы Вы сделать воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: Также добавлю, что это может быть связано с тем, что вот эти скриншоты - сделаны с проекта работающего через webpack-dev-server с hmr, а если посмотреть на странице, без hmr, то все отработает. Я натыкался как-то на схожий баг (но не в одном из ваших пакетов): https://github.com/gaearon/babel-plugin-react-transform/issues/57. Там Даня Абрамов пишет что для функциональных компонентов нужен другой подход на уровне реализации трансформера, возможно на пакеты которые Вы используете это так же распространяется

Comment: В общем: 1. склейте воспроизводимый пример. 2. Проверьте работу этой штуки без hmr-магии. Если по-прежнему не работает, тогда надо подумать

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Comment: @M_Denis, тут отлаживаться надо, с ходу не вижу. Сейчас времени нету, позже на неделе посмотрю если не ответят

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, спасибо за разъяснения. Я склеил код и запустил без hot module replacement, но не помогло. Посмотреть можно тут: https://skunshd.github.io/react-test-example/ Симптомы те же - приходит пустой компонент. Подскажите пожалуйста какие есть идеи на этот счёт.

Comment: @M_Denis, как я написал уже, надо отлаживаться, прям по порядку посмотреть какой js-код генерится из jsx, и исходя из этого сделать какие-то выводы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все было очень просто: оказывается, [jsx не понимает самописные компоненты с маленькой буквы](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), все что с маленькой буквы - считается предопределенным на уровне библиотеки элементом (html тегом то есть). Об этом я сам с большим удивлением сегодня узнал, написав перед этим тьму продакшн кода на реакте. Просто всю жизнь следовал стайлгайдам и проблем не было))

Ну то есть достаточно просто просто назвать ваш компонент с большой буквы:

```
import MultipleHoles from './multipleHoles';
```